# set up Cron job to run PHP script

Tags: php, cron

I know this question has been asked before, but none of the answers are working for me.
I'm trying to run a simple PHP script every night at midnight. I created a file called "autoDelete.php" that contains just this code:

```
<?php 
  include 'my-database-connection.php';
  mysql_query("DELETE FROM meetings WHERE indexDate < NOW()");
?>
```

I know this script is working because if I navigate to it in a browser, it does what it should.

I then set up the Cron job (via GoDaddy cPanel) to run every minute, with a command to run the script using this:

```
* * * * /usr/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/autoDelete.php
```

However, this is not working. I suspect this has something to do with whatever precedes the "/home" in the command.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

1) cron jobs' default "working directory" is the home directory of the user ID they're running under. That'd most likely be `/home/username` in this case. That means if you have any relative-pathed `include`/`require` commands, they're going to be relative to /home/username, NOT /home/username/public_html. Make SURE that all necessary files are accessible.

2) You're simply assuming the query call succeeded. That's exactly the wrong the thing to do. Calls to external resources (DBs in particular) have exactly ONE way to succeed, and a near infinite number of ways to fail. ALWAYS check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Combining these two (failing to include your connection script, and failing to check for failure), and you end up with what you've got: "nothing" happening. At least try something like

```
mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The error message will become your script's output, and get emailed to the controlling account's mailbox.

Comment: OK Marc, I added the "mysql_error" line. Here is the Command line: /usr/bin/wget /home/cPanel-username/public_html/admin/autoDelete.php 
and here is the error message: /home/cPanel-username/public_html/admin/autoDelete.php: Scheme missing.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues in the past with running PHP scripts in a cron job when trying to invoke the PHP binary directly. My solution was to use wget in the cron job since the script was servable by Apache anyway (0 0 * * * wget url/of/script.php). Apache already has the right PHP environment set up so might as well just ask it to handle the job.

Comment: I did try "wget" - and it did work when I ran the cron every minute. But when I adjusted it to anything longer than every minute - it didn't work! I even had a GoDaddy tech check it. They were not very helpful ( because, in all fairness, its outside of what they are willing to support) - other than to suggest that I should use the "php -q".

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If it works on the once-per-minute interval, it should also work on the once-per-day interval. Does the daily job look like this: `0 0 * * * wget /url/of/script.php`?

Comment: I don't have the question mark at the end of the string. Here's what I have: wget /home/username/public_html/admin/autoDelete.php

Comment: lol, that's not part of the job. If it looks exactly like that, then it _should_ work. Same exact job as one that does work, but just a different interval. Have you tried a slightly different time than midnight, maybe 1AM? There might be something odd with GoDaddy's hosting. I never use them for anything.

Comment: I tried every 30 mins and every 5 mins - basically nothing worked except every minute. Again - the tech was also somewhat mystified, but yet she ran her own job that had no issues so assumed I had bad code.

Comment: Yeah that's very strange. If the wget job doesn't work I wouldn't expect the php -q job to work either. Something's up with cron if your syntax is right.